# MySQL server crashes when importing CSV files with a lot of spaces characters

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I need to import about 1TB of csv files to a MariaDB MySQL database, but the server no longer responds when importing some files. Does anyone know how I can do to avoid these crashes?

The mysql server is hosted on windows 10 64bit, the mariadb version is 10.1.31.
This is the query I run:

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 
'x:/Storage/DBP/$file'
IGNORE
INTO TABLE `$dataTableName`
LINES TERMINATED BY "\n"
(@ff)
SET 
`email` = REGEXP_SUBSTR(@ff, "^[^;:,]*"),
`content` = REGEXP_SUBSTR(@ff, "[^;:,]+$");
```

I have analyzed the files that cause the server to crash and I have come to the conclusion that too many spaces chars (about 1.5 MB of space chars) cause the server to crash. I have also analyzed the mariadb logs, but it does not cause any log when it crashes. The files in question are also similar and similar to the others, same size (300MB-10GB).

Comment: Have you try mysqlimport with --verbose,  --debug-check ( to check memory and open file usage at exit) or --debug-inf?.

Comment: What is the exact behaviour when you say 'crash'?

Comment: Provide us with a sample line and the expected values for `email` and `content`.

Comment: for crash I mean no answer for whole hours, then after many hours I stopped it. email is the user's email address, while the content is a string of about 10-20 characters.